# HDMI output change after closing a lid on windows 7 laptop

Tags: windows-7, hdmi

I have a new laptop with Win7 I connect HDMI tv to play a film. When I close a lid, the screen changes its resolution and instead of seeing a film on full screen I see a patch of desktop and half of the movie. Is there a way to set screen size, resolution or whatever is needed, that after closing the lid nothing changes on HDMI?

Comment: Which laptop and with lid opened is it working as it should?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After connecting the monitor/TV, press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and select **Projector only** as shown below. If that doesn't work, try **Duplicate**:

[image]